# Reference data from a growing number of Excel files / CSVs in Tableau?

Tags: excel, csv, tableau-api

I want to analyse data using Tableau. The data comes from simulation runs. Each result of a run is saved to a single CSV/ Excel file, e. g.:

> SimRun1.xlsx , SimRun2.xlsx, ... SimRunN.xlsx

There is also a (single) file which stores some meta-data of those simulation runs (each name, when it run, ...), called:

> SimOverview.xlsx

I want to compare/analyze various simulation runs within Tableau. Can Tableau automatically add new .xlsx/ CSV files, for example based on **SimOverview.xlsx** or do I have to add addtional files manually each time a simulation run was finished?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do this is to create a Union of the source files. When you are setting up the data connection you can click the drop-down menu at the right of the data source and select "convert to union". Then you can define the union using a wildcard in the name (eg "simRun*") and, every time you refresh the data, all files meeting the criterion you just defined will be added to the data source.